# client not able to communicate to the server through a webservice

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
 at org.apache.axis.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:101)
 at org.apache.axis.SOAPPart.getAsSOAPEnvelope(SOAPPart.java:701)
 at org.apache.axis.Message.getSOAPEnvelope(Message.java:435)
 at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.MustUnderstandChecker.invoke(MustUnderstandChecker.java:62)
 at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:206)
 at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
 at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
 at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
 at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
 at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
 at com.medplus.hub.results.webservice.ResultsServicePortStub.getHL7Results(Unknown Source)
 at hl7.HL7QuestHub.getResults(HL7QuestHub.java:4884)
 at hl7.HL7QuestHub.execute(HL7QuestHub.java:4837)
 at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:195)
 at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:520)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.readV3Record(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.xerces.utils.ChunkyByteArray.fill(ChunkyByteArray.java:222)
 at org.apache.xerces.utils.ChunkyByteArray.(ChunkyByteArray.java:98)
 at org.apache.xerces.readers.DefaultReaderFactory.createReader(DefaultReaderFactory.java:153)
 at org.apache.xerces.readers.DefaultEntityHandler.startReadingFromDocument(DefaultEntityHandler.java:491)
 at org.apache.xerces.framework.XMLParser.parseSomeSetup(XMLParser.java:312)
 at org.apache.xerces.framework.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:1080)
 at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.parse(DeserializationContext.java:227)
 at org.apache.axis.SOAPPart.getAsSOAPEnvelope(SOAPPart.java:696)
 ... 13 more
```

Does this mean that the client is behind a slow connection? There is no firewall in place. 
What parameters do I need to configure to see if it resolves my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Start with a basic network test by having the client attempt to telnet on the server's listening port and even perhaps send a HTTP request